# Error al iniciar linux en maquina virtual

Tags: linux, virtualbox, linux-mint

Tengo VirtualBox instalado en mi PC, donde tengo un máquina virtual y una base de datos muy importante que no quiero perder.

Estaba intentando instalar los guest additions en ella cuando de repente reinicié y ahora no me deja seguir. He intentado ejecutar diferentes comandos que encontré para ignorar el error y arrancar, pero no me funciona. De acuerdo a lo que leí, es un problema de particiones, controladores, drivers o kernel. Este es mi error:

```
BusyBox v1.27.2 (ubuntu 1:1.27.2-2ubuntu3) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
```

Ese es el que me sale principalmente, cuando Ingreso **"Exit"**

> (initramfs) exit

Arroja lo siguiente :

```
Gave up waiting for root file system device. Common problems
- Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
 - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
- Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT! UUID=9a963566-b633-4371-9c73-21efb696f184 does not exit.
Dropping to a shell!
BusyBox v1.27.2 (ubuntu 1:1.27.2-2ubuntu3) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
```

He encontrado información que con el disco o la memoria de instalación de linux y ciertos comandos, pero como bien saben es una máquina virtual y es un disco ISO descargado de la página web oficial, entonces no sé como habría que hacer, agradecería su ayuda, es de mucha muchísima importancia, igualmente seguiré buscando información.

Comment: Quizas deberias formular la pregunta en otro sitio unicamente para linux y si es posible en inglés para que te respondan en breve

Answer (score 0):

Hasta donde entiendo, por el error de:

```
ALERT! UUID=9a963566-b633-4371-9c73-21efb696f184 does not exit.
```

No tienes un disco montado, algo que se sugiere es esto:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
sudo chroot /mnt
update-initramfs -u
update-grub
reboot
```

Donde supongo `/dev/sda1` es la partición del disco duro al que hace referencia.

Lo tomé de [aquí](https://askubuntu.com/questions/516217/alert-dev-disk-by-uuid-xxxxxxxxx-does-not-exist-dropping-to-a-shell):

Comment: Hola @mrc_es. Si eso es una posible pero si iniciara la maquina en este caso no pasa del inicio,es decir, después de que presenta el logo de linux mint se queda, queda en consola  (initramfs), eh intentado igualmente la solución y me devuelve **"sh: sudo: not found"**. Te agradecería que me pudieras ayudar :C

Comment: Inicia como super usuario y corre los mismos comandos pero sin `sudo`.

Comment: Como inicio como super usuario ? @mrc_es **sudo su** no funciona

Comment: Al escribir los comandos sin el **sudo** me devuleve **mounting /dev/sdaX on /mnt failed: no such file or directory**

Comment: Poniendo `$ su` en la terminal, te va a preguntar la contraseña de superusuario; puedes buscarlo en internet. Y revisa cuál es la partición de tu disco que será montada, tal vez te sirva poner `lsblk` para ver si es de tipo sda1 o sda2; eso también lo puedes buscar en internet.

Comment: Na no funciona :C siempre sale **sh: su: not found** o en su defecto cualquier comando que ponga.